# Making a prediction with must and can't

Tags: modal-verbs

Can we make a prediction about the future using "can't" and "must"? For example, "we can't be late, we've got now plenty of time to get there". " She must be really happy when she learns about your new job". Thanks in advanve :)

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your sentences is idiomatic.

*We can't be late* would usually mean 'we must not risk the possibility of being late' You might say *We can't **possibly** be late now, we have plenty of time to get there.*

*She must be really happy* would mean 'she is certain to be happy now'. As a prediction, you would have to say *She will be really happy.*

Comment: Thank you, Kate